# why is the following sentence classified as a compound sentence?

Tags: grammar

According to "ESL Writing" by Mary Ellen Munoz Page, the following sentence:

**"I baked an apple pie, but I forgot to put cinnamon in it."**

is classified as *a compound sentence*,

whereas

**"Sonia speaks English but does not write it."**

is considered to be *a simple sentence*.

---

I don't see the difference between these sentences. I would omit the pronoun "I" after "but" in the first sentence, and classify it as a simple sentence, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [1] [*I baked an apple pie*], *but* [*I forgot to put cinnamon in it*].
>
> [2] *Sonia* [*speaks English*] *but* [*does not write it*].

[1] contains a main-clause coordination (bracketed). Each coordinate could stand alone as a sentence, and hence traditional grammar calls this a compound sentence

By contrast, [2] has a lower-level coordination where this time the coordinates are just verb phrases which could not stand alone as sentences, and hence this is called a simple sentence.

Answer (score 2):

A compound sentence has two complete sentences, which means each has a subject and predicate.  (The second subject just happens to be the same as the first, but you could also have "**I** *baked* an apple pie, but **my dog** *ate* it before I had a chance to taste it.")

Your second sentence only has one subject (Sonia).